# Problems building libmodbus 3.0.6 ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, compiling, gcc, serial-port

I am finding that libmodbus http://libmodbus.org/ is compiling incorrectly on both my laptop and desktop running Ububtu 14.04 both were upgraded from 11.10 some time ago. I have tried using the live CD version of 14.04 and it compiles fine.

To repoduce the problem download and unpack 3.0.6 edit /tests/unit-test-server so that it is using a valid serial device on your pc look for /dev/ttyUSB0

./configure
make
cd tests
sudo ./unit-test-server rtu

on my pc I am getting an ERROR connection reset by peer:read  message

Any suggestions?